Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper
2024-07-01T17:48:02.915Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception
{
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
"stack": [
"Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper'",
"Require stack:",
"- /var/task/index.js",
"- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
"    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
"    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
"    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
"    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
]
}

Maybe https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/30717 ?

You seem to be running that in Lambda, which uses a Node runtime which utilises JavaScript SDK V3.
The package you refer to is an archived package from JavaScript V2 and is unlikely to work with V3.

but i am unsing v2 and the node version i am using currently is node 16 only , where can i find the fix

Did you upload a Lambda layer with that package?

I have removed the Datamapper, and swiched to nova-odm still getting Import Error
{
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '@nova-odm/mapper'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
}

Same question. Did you import the package in a layer?
